# Haskell error: Could not deduce (Random a0) arising from

Tags: haskell

I was playing around with the random function that gives an infinite list of random values as shown in Chapter 9 of "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good". The code goes like this:

```
randoms' :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]
randoms' gen = let (value, newGen) = random gen
               in value : randoms' newGen
```

In order to record the random generators, I changed `randoms'` a bit to the following:

```
randoms'' :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [(a, g)]
randoms'' gen = let (value, newGen) = random gen
                in (value, newGen) : randoms'' newGen
```

It works as expected.

Then I rewrote it in the style of list comprehension:

```
randoms''' :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [(a, g)]
randoms''' gen = random gen : [random gen' | (_, gen') <- randoms''' gen]
```

This time, the complier gives the error: **Could not deduce (Random a0) arising from a use of ‘randoms'''’...... The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous...**

However, if I specify the type of `randoms'''` with concrete types, e.g.,

```
randoms''' :: StdGen -> [(Int, StdGen)]
randoms''' gen = random gen : [random gen' | (_, gen') <- randoms''' gen]
```

it works fine again and gives exactly the same result as `randoms''`.

I wonder why the type inference works for `randoms''` but fails for `randoms'''`. Can anyone tell me why these two are not equivalent and how to fix the code of `randoms'''`?

Furthermore, I experimented with the test code having the similar structure:

```
generate :: (Integral a, RealFrac b) => a -> (b,a)
generate m = let x = 1.2^^m in (x, ceiling x)

foo :: (Integral g, RealFrac a) => g -> [(a,g)]
foo gen = let (value, newGen) = generate gen
          in (value, newGen) : foo newGen

foo' :: (Integral g, RealFrac a) => g -> [(a, g)]
foo' gen = generate gen : [generate gen' | (_, gen') <- foo' gen]

foo'' :: (Integral g, RealFrac a) => g -> [(a, g)]
foo'' gen = [generate gen' | gen' <- gen : map snd (foo'' gen)]
```

It turns out `foo`, `foo'` and `foo''` all work fine. Apparently, it is not a problem of monomorphism vs polymorphism. It seems to be a problem specific to `random`.

Comment: You throw away the actual value generated by `randoms'''` (`(_, gen') <- ...`) so the compiler has no idea at which type to instantiate the use of `randoms'''`; there is no reason for it to pick the same type `a` that is the output, nor any other particular type, so it is ambiguous. In the monomorphic case, there is no instantiation possible - naturally it may only pick `Int` for the recursive case.

Answer (score 2):

```
(_, gen') <- randoms''' gen
```

Which type has `_` here? You probably think it should be the `a` given in `randoms'''`'s signature. However, it's arbitrary. It might be `()`, it might be `Char`. Everything could work here, since you don't use it anyway. We can force it to have the same type as `random gen'`:

```
randoms''' gen = random gen : [random gen' `asTypeOf` x | x@(_, gen') <- randoms''' gen]
```

`asTypeOf` is a standard function and basically a type constrained version of `const`:

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf = const
```

With this function, we can determine the type of `x` and therefore the type of `_`, since the type of `random gen'` is known.

Comment: Your first solution using `asTypeOf` solves the problem. However, the second solution `randomList` gives rise to almost exactly the same error message (and it works again if the type signature is set to be monomorphic). I still don't get why the type of `_` is arbitrary simply because it is not used; there is no such a problem in the monomorphic case anyway. Perhaps the mechanism of type inference is somewhat different between the monomorphic and polymorphic cases?

Comment: @Oyu I removed the wrong function. I have no idea why it worked when I've tried it. Either way, `_` is "used". It is part of the result of a `random` call. If we use `let (val, gen) = random (mkStdGen 0) :: (a, StdGen)`, we end up with another generator `gen` depending on the type. For `a ~ Int`, we get `(9106162675347844341,1346387765 2103410263)`. For `a ~ Char`, we get `('\589059',40014 40692)`. After all, you have to call `next` often enough to create a uniform distribution over your whole range of values.

Comment: I have experimented with some foo codes as re-edited at the end of my original post. Can you give me some comments about what you think?